# Why isn't the "Checkbox hack" working on my 3d element?

Tags: html, css, checkbox, css-animations

My "checkbox hack" isn't doing anything when in the toggled state.

I have a 3d cube that is rotating and I want it to sorta spin and get bigger when it is clicked on, so I tried using the checkbox hack in order to change the animation when it is in the toggled state. However, regardless of what I do (i.e. change background color of elements, change font size, change scale of .cube, etc.) Absolutely nothing happens when the label is in toggle state. Can someone help me figure out what I did wrong?

Here is my current code.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html {
  width: 100vw;
  height: auto;
}

body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: antiquewhite;
  color: #333;
  font-size: 100px;
}

.cube {
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transform-origin: right;
  top: calc(50%);
  left: calc(50%);
  position: absolute;
  animation: rotateCube 8s infinite linear;
}

label {
  position: absolute;
  top: calc(50% - 1em);
  left: calc(50% - 1em);
  height: 2em;
  width: 2em;
  z-index: 10;
}

#toggle {
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 1;
}

.face {
  height: 2em;
  width: 2em;
  background-color: whitesmoke;
  position: absolute;
  margin: -1em;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  box-shadow: inset 1px 1px 2px #555, inset -1px 0px 2px #555;
}

.face span {
  font-size: 50px;
}

.front {
  transform: translateZ(1em);
}

.right {
  transform: rotateY(90deg) translateZ(1em);
}

.back {
  transform: rotateY(180deg) translateZ(1em);
}

.left {
  transform: rotateY(-90deg) translateZ(1em);
}

.top {
  transform: rotateX(90deg) translateZ(1em);
}

.bottom {
  transform: rotateX(-90deg) translateZ(1em)
}

input:checked~.face {
  background-color: blue;
  animation: rotateCube2 8s forwards;
}

@keyframes rotateCube {
  0% {
    transform: rotateY(0deg) rotateX(-15deg);
  }
  50% {
    transform: rotateY(360deg) rotateX(15deg)
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotateY(720deg) rotateX(-15deg)
  }
}

@keyframes rotateCube2 {
  50% {
    transform: rotateY(90deg) rotateX(90deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotateY(180deg) rotateX(180deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="cube-button">
  <input type="checkbox" id="toggle">
  <label for="toggle"></label>
  <div class="cube">
    <div class="face front"><span>Click Me</span></div>
    <div class="face left"></div>
    <div class="face right"></div>
    <div class="face back"></div>
    <div class="face top"></div>
    <div class="face bottom"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem occurs here -

[image: CSS Code Snippet]

The above selector says that the checked state input will look out for all its siblings that comes after it in the DOM...
The Problem is, there is **no sibling with a class face**

*There is only one sibling with a class cube*

So to modify the styles of .face when input is checked, the CSS selector will look something like this

```
input:checked ~ .cube > .face { ... }
```

and to modify the styles of .cube -

```
input:checked ~ .cube { ... }
```